# Relational algebra notation of the employees in the same Department as employee 3

Tags: database, relational-algebra

Someone please explain this

```
ρ emp2.surname,emp2.forenames (
    σ employee.empno = 3 ^ employee.depno = emp2.depno (
        employee × (ρemp2employee)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query relates "employee #3" with another "employee" by virtue of both being in the same department. Therefore, you need two listings (ahem, tables) of employees. Since you have two instances of the same thing, then you need to alias (technically rename) at least one of them. The most generic relationship between two tables is Cartesian product. So, now that you build cartesian product, you have to restrict a) employees in the first one to being #3, and b) employees in both tables belonging to the same department. Final step is selecting only those employee attributes which are relevant to the question asked.